# Enabling sticky session mode for Apache/Tomcat load balancing

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, httpd.conf

I am trying to enable sticky sessions in Apache, however it is not working. Below are the changes made by me. Am I missing something?

I do not see any error in the access log, however request from one user is still going to other server.

**Step 1**: Added below in httpd.conf of load balancer of server1 & server2

```
<Proxy balancer://marsBalancer>
BalancerMember http://server1fullname:8080  route=server1 
BalancerMember http://server2fullname:8080  route=server2
ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /marsWAR/ balancer://marsBalancer/marsWAR/
```

**Step 2**: Updated below in server.xml

a) server.xml in server1

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="server1">
```

b) server.xml in server2

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="server2">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `marsWAR` part from the ProxyPass directive :

```
ProxyPass /marsWAR/ balancer://marsBalancer/
```

If it still does not work, try specifying the session `<id>` directly to the ProxyPass directive by adding the following code:

```
ProxyPass /marsWAR/ balancer://marsBalancer/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
```

Comment: I don't know two persons replied but still the op not marked any answer. They are showing to reward +100 or +50 but mostly time expires and they have many answers but not marking

Comment: Hi Ghayal , I will be checking this options on monday IST and will mark as answered if it is working . this issue is happening in our development server and for any deployment/changes in development server , I've to go via. change request process which need 1 day lead time as well approval from change management team .

Comment: I think , this should work . will mark this as unanswered if not working .

Answer (score 2):

1. version numbers of everything = ?
2. It has to be `stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid` as Cookie name is uppercase, but path parameter name is lowercase. Supporting path parameters also needs `scolonpathdelim=On` [1]  See also "Troubleshooting load balancer stickyness" on that documentation page.

[1] http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#stickyness_implementation